# Dell M6700 ethernet (e1000e) not working in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, dell, intel, ethernet, e1000

I have 13.04 64-bit on my Dell M6700. Wired ethernet worked for a while, but now stopped working.

As an extra information, the ethernet works through the docking station (port replicator), but not via the plug on the back of the laptop. I have checked that it works with win7, so it is not a hw problem.

The issue is present with `3.8.0-19 kernel`, but it is not present on `3.8.0-16 kernel`. The exact problem is that the kernel simply does not see that a cable is plugged in, i.e., nothing goes into `syslog` or `dmesg`.

More details:

```
fery@fery-M6700:~$ lspci |grep Eth
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
```

The driver is the e1000e module.

```
fery@fery-M6700:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.8.0-19-generic (buildd@allspice) (gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) ) #30-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 1 16:35:23 UTC 2013
```

Is this the right place to ask this problem? If not, where should I go?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on my Dell Latitude E6520.  The following fix worked for me:

```
echo on | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/device/power/control
```

I found the solution here: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?62825-Ringtail-not-working-with-Intel-NIC

Good luck!